# Piwigo on nextcloudpi

Tags: raspbian

Piwigo installation on a “fresh” nextcloudpi device fails.
The installation follows [this](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-the-piwigo-photo-gallery-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-with-apache2-mariadb-and-php-7-2-support/) documentation.

Main problem is, that when I request the address https://radius.ddnss.de/piwigo the webserver redirects the request to https://radius.ddnss.de, that is the root URI of nextcloud server.

My question is, what should be considered for piwigo?

Comment: `The installation follows this documentation.` which documentation?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But your question is a mystery to me. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: @Dirk https://websiteforstudents.com/install-the-piwigo-photo-gallery-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-with-apache2-mariadb-and-php-7-2-support/

Comment: @Ingo Sadly the problem is not so. As described, nextcloud somehow does not allow requests to any other subdirectory which belongs to another application. Why?